# Finding an elementary function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

Can someone please help me find any elementary function that satisfies

- $f(0) = 6$
- $f(1) = f(-1) = 4$
- $f(2) = f(-2) = 1$?

I have been trying for nearly an hour, but I still can't figure it out.  Only the points listed above matter. Nothing else matters (I don't care what $f(1.5)$ or $f(3)$ or $f(-100)$ are).

The symmetry motivated me to try and use absolute value, but it didn't get me anywhere since there is nonconstant slope.

Comment: Well...$f(x)=6-\frac {x^2}2-\frac {3|x|}2$ works.  Is that elementary enough?

Comment: I used a program called Geogebra Classic and the option "conic by five points". So, I've get the hyperbole $-10x^2+y^2-15y=-54$ (you can consider one of the parts and get a implict function).

Comment: i need a function in $x$, but @lulu's answer works.

Comment: @Na'omi unfortunately conics aren't, strictly speaking, functions of $x.$

Comment: @Chickenmancer, you're right. But I have a doubt, in this case I got a hyperbole with axis $x=0$ and all of the points given by the question are at the lower branch of the hyperbole. So in this case I couldn't have an implicit function in $x$? Thanks very much for the help and I'm so sorry by any incovenience, Ekesh. Happy because you got better answers.

Comment: Note that the values you are given are symmetric about $x=0$, so you should look first for an even function for which $f(x)=f(-x)$. ($|x|$ and $x^2$ are both even, which is why they appear in answers and suggestions)

Comment: Note also that if you are looking for a polynomial solution you will not get integer coefficients - $f(0)=6$ means that the constant term will be $6$, and if coefficients were integers, this would make $f(2)$ even, but the value you have is odd.

Comment: What do you mean by elementary functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many functions work.  Here's one way to get a fairly simple one:

We can fit a quadratic through the values at $0,1,2$.  That leads us to $6-\frac 12(x^2+3x)$.  Now we can use the absolute value to extend this symmetrically to the negative values, arriving at $$f(x)=6-\frac {x^2}2-\frac {3|x|}2$$

Alternatively, we could fit a quartic through the five given points and thereby avoid the use of the absolute value, though at the cost of increasing the degree.  I think the quadratic (with the absolute value) is the more elementary solution.

Comment: +1 for your Nice answer. I have one doubt, is it possible to exist any function with odd degree which satisfy our requirements.

Comment: Sure.  $6 + \frac x{10} - \frac {9 x^2}{4} - \frac {x^3}8 + \frac {x^4}4 + \frac {x^5}{40}$ works.  Given any finite list of $n$ points $(x_i,y_i)$ (with the $x_i$ distinct), you can always fit a polynomial of degree $n-1$ through them.  Now, you specify $5$ points so you'd get a quartic...to get the example I got, I just added the point $(-3,-3)$ to your list.   Nothing special about that value...Any value not on the original quartic will work.  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InterpolatingPolynomial%5B(0,6),(1,4),(-1,4),(2,1),(-2,1)(-3,--3)%5D) does the rest.

Comment: thank you sir...

Answer (score 2):

let's assume the function be,
$$f(x)=ax^4+bx^2+c$$
now,we get,
$$f(0)=a.0^4+b.0^2+c=6........(1)$$
$$f(\pm 1)=a+b+c=4.....(2)$$
$$f(\pm 2)=16a+4b+c=1.....(3)$$
solving these equations we get,$a=\dfrac{1}{4},b=-\dfrac{9}{4},c=6$
Hence,
$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{4}x^4-\dfrac{9}{4}x^2+6$$

Comment: +1. Nice answer. Is it necessary that the function to be even degree?

Comment: For the given condition,yes it must have to be of even degree...because $f(-1)=f(1)$

Answer (score 0):

Note that if given a function $h(x)$ where $h(-x)=x$, if we can find a function $g(x)$ such that $g(h(0))=6$, $g(h(1))=4$, $g(h(2))=1$, then we can take $f(x) = g(h(x))$.  Rakibul Islam Prince seems to have taken $h(x) = x^2$ and $g(x)=\frac14 x^2-\frac94x+6$. lulu seems to have taken $h(x) = |x|$ and $g(x) = 6-\frac12x^2-\frac32x$ (note that $|x|^2$ is the same thing as $x^2$), but their answer can also be derived from $h(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=6-\frac12x-\frac32\sqrt{|x|}$.